# Difference between $this->a and $this->$b in PHP

Tags: php, oop

What is the difference between:

`$this->$a` and `$this->b`

In my class I have this:

```
class someClass{
    public $a;
    function aFunction(){
      $this->a = 5;
      $this->$b = 7;
    }
 }
```

what does having the extra '$' do in the `$this->$b`

Comment: It's a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a lot of difference:

`$this->a` refers to the property `$a` of your class

`$this->$b` in the other hand refers to the property by the name which is stored in variable `$b` as a string:

```
$b = "a";
$this->$b equals $this->a

$b = "hello"
$this->$b equals $this->hello
```